# How to have a Django relational database with four tables?

Tags: python, django, django-models, frameworks

I am creating a website using Django and have a problem with the database!
I have four tables (topics, questions, answers, and images). Each one of these tables has an id column and I would like to connect these four tables together.

I have tried to use a `ForeignKey()` but that didn't work out. I am receiving an error message. I don't know if I can use `ManyToManyField()` in this case, because it is only one column that I am trying to connect.

This is the code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class topics(models.Model):
    topic_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    topic_level = models.BooleanField()
    topic_name = models.TextField()

class questions(models.Model):
    question_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    questions_type = models.BooleanField()


class answers(models.Model):
    answer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()

class images (models.Model):
    image_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image_blob = models.BinaryField()
```

This is the code with the `ForeignKey()`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class topics(models.Model):
    topic_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    topic_level = models.BooleanField()
    topic_name = models.TextField()
    topic_question = models.ForeignKey(questions, on_delete=CASCADE)
    topic_answer = models.ForeignKey(answers, on_delete=CASCADE)
    topic_image = models.ForeignKey(images, on_delete=CASCADE)


class questions(models.Model):
    question_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    questions_type = models.BooleanField()
    question_topic = models.ForeignKey(topics, on_delete=CASCADE)
    question_answer = models.ForeignKey(answers, on_delete=CASCADE)
    question_image = models.ForeignKey(images, on_delete=CASCADE)


class answers(models.Model):
    answer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    answer_topic = models.ForeignKey(topics, on_delete=CASCADE)
    answer_question = models.ForeignKey(questions, on_delete=CASCADE)
    answer_image = models.ForeignKey(images, on_delete=CASCADE)

class images (models.Model):
    image_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image_blob = models.BinaryField()
    image_topic = models.ForeignKey(topics, on_delete=CASCADE)
    image_question = models.ForeignKey(questions, on_delete=CASCADE)
    image_answer= models.ForeignKey(answers, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

And this is the error message that I am receiving:

> topic_question = models.ForeignKey(questions, on_delete=CASCADE)
>   NameError: name 'questions' is not defined

Comment: Just a note please follow  [naming convections](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-convections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point you're trying to use the `question` class name for indicating the related model, such class is not defined, as the error states. When you're referencing a model that is defined later in the code you must enclose the name in `""`:

```
topic_question = models.ForeignKey("questions", on_delete=CASCADE)
```

Here is the related docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: How does that answer the the OP question of creating foreign keys?

Comment: @devdob Yeah, my bad I was writing the aswer for another question using an 
 editor and copy the wrong aswer, I've updated

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I have done what you have suggested and have a question about it. I haven't seen any of the tutorials using parenthesis and I would like to know why?
And when I did what you had suggested I had received a new error that I hadn't received earlier when I had ran my code without ForeignKey().
The new error is:
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @MajedSaaeddin, in tutorials you have seen models always are defined in order of use. Read the link I  post  in the answer.

Comment: @About your new error is Python error and not have to do with Django, you have some bad indented block or you've missed some `)`. Sometimes copy/pasting Python code change spaces by tabs and vice-versa. Check all your spaces are spaces or all your tabs are tabs.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Sorry to bother but, I am receiving this error now,

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'answer_question' to answers without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate
existing rows).
Please select a fix:

 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: Do you have answers in the answer table?

Comment: On the other hand, you don't need `answer_question` in `answers` model, you already has established that relationship with `question_answer` in the model `question` which, by the way, should be a `OneToMany` field, since a question can have none or several answers.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda This is just not working, I have connected the `Class topics` with three `ForeignKey` and the `Class questions` to two `ForeignKey` and the `Class questions` to one `ForeignKey` and the last one to none. But this is just not working and I am receiving the same mistake with two choices.